# How to pass values from dropdown to inputs on select ? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I don't know how to pass values from dropdown on select to 4 inputs. My dropdown showing address as it should be but I struggle to pass each value to separate inputs.e.g address_1 should be in one input where is flat number, address_2 where is street etc.

```
 const [select,setSelect]=useState()

 <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}>  

 <option>Select Address</option>
                    {getAddressData?.address? (
                      getAddressData?.address?.map((address: any, id) => (
                        <option>{`${address.Address_1},${address.Address_2}, ${address.Town}, ${address.County}`}</option>

                     <input>

                    type={'text'}
                    name={'flatNumber'}
                    placeholder="Flat Number"
                    value={select}

                   </input>
```

Right now I have whole line of address e.g (30 Ballot Street,Smethick,West Midlands) in the whole one input.

Comment: So do you want to show the address in 4 inputs instead of the current one?

Comment: @DreamBold yes. 4 inputs showing separately county, address1 ,address2 and town

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code. It's live here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-firefly-0qdrij?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState({
    Address_1: "",
    Address_2: "",
    Town: "",
    pafCounty: ""
  });

  let getAddressData = {};
  getAddressData.address = [
    {
      Address_1: "Address_1",
      Address_2: "Address_2",
      Town: "Town",
      pafCounty: "pafCounty"
    },
    {
      Address_1: "Address_11",
      Address_2: "Address_22",
      Town: "Town2",
      pafCounty: "pafCounty2"
    }
  ];

  function handleChange(e) {
    setAddress({ ...address, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(address);
  }, [address]);

  return (
    <>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          setAddress(getAddressData?.address[e.target.value]);
        }}
      >
        <option selected disabled>
          Select Address
        </option>
        {getAddressData?.address?.map((address, index) => (
          <option
            key={index}
            value={index}
          >{`${address.Address_1}, ${address.Address_2}, ${address.Town}, ${address.pafCounty}`}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      {Object.keys(address).map((key, index) => (
        <input
          type="text"
          name={key}
          placeholder="Flat Number"
          value={address[key]}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setSelect(e.target.value)`, set it to the original structured address object. You could have the value of the option be the index within the address list, for example, and then `setSelect(getAddressData?.address[2])` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you @ray.  hmmm I'm not sure If I know what you mean.. Is it any chance you can provide an example? I appreciate it

Comment: Look at [Dream Bold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74804465/636077). Each `<option>`'s value is just the index of the address within the `getAddressData.address` array. The select's `onChange` handler uses that index to set the state to the original address object, instead of trying to stringify it into the option value itself and then parse it back out. `<option value={1}>{...}</option>` lets you look up address 1 in the array, etc.